# Activate function after completion of the previous in Update, Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is not the full script. I am only showing the part which I have problem with.

**Issue Faced:**

I wanted to make neat and clean script therefore I only call functions into my update.

I wanted to introduce (*StartGameFreezeMovement*) function into the first line of update.

I couldn't do it. Like the rest of the functions because this one has a timer in it.

**Result Wanted:**

My intention is to find a way for the first function in update to completely finish then load or activate the rest.

How can I achieve this?

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

private CharacterController controller;
public float speed;
private Vector3 moveVector;
private float verticalVelocity;
public float gravity;
private float animationDuration = 3.0f;
public Text text;
private float timer;
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Start ()
{
    text.text = "";
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    if(Time.time < animationDuration)
    {
        PlayerMovingForward();
        return; //getout of if...
    }
    StartText();
    PlayerMovingForward();
    PlayerLeftnRight();
    PlayerFalloffGravity();
}
//----------------------------------
void StartGameFreezeMovement()
{
    if (Time.time < animationDuration)
    {
        PlayerMovingForward();
        return; //getout of if...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My intention is to find a way for the first function in update to
>   completely finished then load or activate the rest.

You need a Coroutine function. The `Update` function is a `void` function. You will have to create a coroutine function and start it once then make sure that it doesn't exit so that it will imitate the `Update` function that is called every frame. This can be done by adding a while loop and yielding every frame.

Finally, turn the `StartGameFreezeMovement` function from `void` into a coroutine function, then change the  `if (Time.time < animationDuration)` to  `while (Time.time < animationDuration)` and yield inside it with `yield return null;` so that other scripts will get chance to execute while waiting for the `StartGameFreezeMovement` function to finish.

Below is a fixed version of the code from your question:

```
private void Start()
{
    //Start once
    StartCoroutine(YieldableUpdate());
}

IEnumerator YieldableUpdate()
{
    //Call and wait for the StartGameFreezeMovement function to finish
    yield return StartGameFreezeMovement();

    //Run forever
    while (true)
    {
        StartText();
        PlayerMovingForward();
        PlayerLeftnRight();
        PlayerFalloffGravity();

        //Wait a frame so that Unity doesn't freeze
        yield return null;
    }
}

IEnumerator StartGameFreezeMovement()
{
    while (Time.time < animationDuration)
    {
        PlayerMovingForward();
        //Wait a frame so that Unity doesn't freeze
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

If you need to check `StartGameFreezeMovement()` more than once the move `yield return StartGameFreezeMovement();` inside the `while (true)` loop otherwise this check will only happen once.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your StartGameFreezeMovement to a bool.

```
bool StartGameFreezeMovement()
{
    if (Time.time < animationDuration)
    {
        PlayerMovingForward();
        return true; //getout of if...
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then change your update function. And then to keep it clean, use return if you do not pass the boolean check to exit the update function early.

```
void Update ()
{
    if (!StartGameFreezeMovement())
    {
        return;
    }

    StartText();
    PlayerMovingForward();
    PlayerLeftnRight();
    PlayerFalloffGravity();
}
```